# Query combination in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder, laravel-7

i am facing a problem where my function have a request from the frontend for sorting the data. So i need to add some condition to my query. I tried to do this way.

```
 $hawker = Hawker_location::withTrashed();

    if($request->district){
        $hawker->where('district', $request->district);
    }

    if($request->type){
        $hawker->where('type', $request->type);
    }

    $hawker->paginate($request->sizePerPage);

    return response()->json($hawker, Response::HTTP_OK);
```

But it return no value for the query but no error. how i can fix this ?

Comment: Replace your pagination query with this `$hawker->paginate($request->get('sizePerPage', 10));` and if the issue is with request sizeperPage not defined it should be solved.

Answer (score 1):

```
Hawker_location::query()->withTrashed()
  ->when($request->has('district'), function($query) { $query->where('district', $request->district)})
  ->when($request->has('type'), function($query) { $query->where('type', $request-> type)})
  ->paginate($request->sizePerPage ?? 10)
```

Comment: Your code will throw an error you have to pass the $request variable in all those function insider ->where() to use them inside.

Comment: it would be helpful to provide at least link to docs for [conditional clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#conditional-clauses)

Answer (score 0):

Try to return the paginator itself

```
return $hawker->paginate($request->input('sizePerPage',50));
```